# Why is the Baron bathing in a dark liquid?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

Why is Baron Harkonnen bathing in a dark liquid? My guess is that the liquid can heal him after the attempt on his life.

Comment: still better than blood plugs

Comment: Evil 101: Wear goth punk stuff and rise from dark goo.  I'm guessing at some point we'll see him say "mwa ha ha ha" while raising grasping fingers to the sky.

Comment: It's a [trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BloodBath) (Warning: TVTropes!)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not a Bacta tank.

Comment: The out-of-universe answer is *'because Villeneuve has watched 'Apocalypse Now' one too many times'*

Comment: @NKCampbell Oh man, I **loved** the blood plugs as an ornament illustrating Baron Harkonnen's over-the-top depravity in the Lynch adaptation. :) The dark liquid of this question's problem is that it's more ambiguous (medical treatment? hard core coffee addict? bathing in the distilled blood of innocent babies?) and veers towards kink-shaming.

Comment: I've seen people suggest that it's supposed to refer to the mechanized state of his home planet (and that it really is basically motor oil). Someone referred to the "leaked shooting script" explaining it on Reddit, but then refused to answer any other questions, which makes me think it might be someone having a laugh.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I happen to have glanced at the leaked script and I can tell you that it's no help. It just describes what he's physically doing (e.g. bathing in an oil-like substance) without offering any commentary whatsoever on the reasons for it.

Comment: @Lexible Not to mention,  the blood plugs were in the original novel.

Comment: @NKCampbell What are the blood plugs? I haven't read the book. Do you mean heart plugs?

Comment: OoU: It helps conceal the lines of Stellen Skarsgârd’s fatsuit while nude. IU: The Baron bathes in adrenochrome, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A cast and crew interview with the film's director indicates that it's '*a healing mud bath*'.

> During one of the most striking visual scenes, **the wounded Harkonnen
> rises ominously from a healing mud bath**, a vision that came from the
> depths of Villeneuve's subconscious.
>
> "I had a dream to have the Baron under the liquid and emerge like a hippopotamus," Villeneuve says.
>
> <sub><sup>[How Stellan Skarsgård transformed to 'Dune's 600-pound, often-naked
> 'monster' villain Baron Harkonnen](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/movies/2021/10/21/dune-baron-harkonnen-how-stellan-skarsgard-owned-600-pound-villain/8447870002/)</sup></sub>

As is annoyingly common with these sorts of interview, they haven't included the quote that they're referencing, but since the director was in the room with the article's author, I think we can be reasonably certain that this is where he got the info from.

---

Out-of-universe, the scene is a fairly obvious homage to Apocalypse Now.

And the oily substance was actually a "*sticky emulsion of water, slime, oil and black color*"

Answer (score 6):

To use a scene directly from the movie as a source, when Rabban approaches the pool one of the assistants standing nearby tells him "he has not finished healing yet." This very strongly imples the bath is some sort of medical treatment for the effects of the poison he was partially exposed to.

Comment: it's a black-ta tank